# React/API/Chart.js: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, error-handling

I am following the documentation here (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) for AJAX and API's to be able to get my API data, display a loading spinner whilst its loading and then display the chart once its loaded.

I however got this error: Line 31:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. Code is below:

Chart3.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  // Note: the empty deps array [] means
  // this useEffect will run once
  // similar to componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {

    let Fore = [];
    let Act = [];
    
    fetch('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2020-09-01T15:30Z/2020-09-10T17:00Z')
      .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
        Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
        Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
        setIsLoaded(true);
      }
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setChartData({
          labels: Fore,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Carbon Intensity Levels",
              data: Act,
              backgroundColor: "#F58A07",
              borderWidth: 4
            }
          ]
          });
          setError(error);
      }})
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return  <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div> <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation="border"/> </div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1></h1>
        <div className="chart">
          <Line
            data={chartData}
            options={{
              responsive: true,
              title: { text: "2020-09-01T15:30Z - 2020-09-10T17:00Z", display: true },
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      autoSkip: true,
                      maxTicksLimit: 100,
                      beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Actual"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Forecast"
                    }

                  }
                ]
              }
            }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Its saying the error is at line 31 which is the part of the code "(error) => {..."

Comment: Your fetch syntax is not correct. Compare it with the example you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
useEffect(() => {

let Fore = [];
let Act = [];

fetch('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2020-09-01T15:30Z/2020-09-10T17:00Z')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    for (const dataObj of data.data) {
    Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
    Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
   }
   setIsLoaded(true);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
    setChartData({
      labels: Fore,
      datasets: [
       {
        label: "Carbon Intensity Levels",
        data: Act,
        backgroundColor: "#F58A07",
        borderWidth: 4
       }
      ]
    });
   setError(error);
 })
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this which has got rid of one error but error now says "Error: res.data.data is not iterable" so I will try to fix this now

Comment: Try to use this callback in 2nd then(

(({data}) => {
  data.forEach(dataObj => {
    Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
    Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
  });
 setIsLoaded(true)
}))

Comment: Didn't work but solved it by puting a .finally at the end and having setIsLoaded(true) in there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, that solution did not work but I found one that has worked code snippet below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  // Note: the empty deps array [] means
  // this useEffect will run once
  // similar to componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {

    let Fore = [];
    let Act = [];
     
    fetch('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2020-09-01T15:30Z/2020-09-10T17:00Z')
      .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
        Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
        Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
        setIsLoaded(true);
      }
         // Note: it's important to handle errors here
         // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
         // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setChartData({
          labels: Fore,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Carbon Intensity Levels",
              data: Act,
              backgroundColor: "#F58A07",
              borderWidth: 4
            }
          ]
          });
          setError(error);
      })
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return  <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div> <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation="border"/> </div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1></h1>
        <div className="chart">
          <Line
            data={chartData}
            options={{
              responsive: true,
              title: { text: "2020-09-01T15:30Z - 2020-09-10T17:00Z", display: true },
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      autoSkip: true,
                      maxTicksLimit: 100,
                      beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Actual"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Forecast"
                    }

                  }
                ]
              }
            }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

However now as I have caught the error it is dsiplaying on screen "Error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" so I think that my api data is maybe not being parsed properly but cant work out why